# Html button border line remove outline on hover after click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML button and I can't get the border to go away. I've tried border:none; along with on each of the clickable behaviors that it's managed. So on active, hover and focus adding outline: none; and border-line: none all still putting a black line around a button that is on an orange background image.

```css
.gsbutton {
 position: absolute;
 float: left;
 margin: -10px 183px;
 align-items: right; 
 width: 135px;
 height: 50px;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5K46.png);
 z-index: -1; 
}
button[type="reset"]:focus, active, hover {
    outline: none; 
 border: none; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="attributes.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- page bar header navigation tabs -->
<div class="head_bg">
 <div class="wrap">
  <div class="logo">
   <a href="index.html">
    <img src="file:///C:/Develop/CodeSamples/manage-landing-page-master/images/logo.svg"></img>
   </a>
  </div>
  <nav class="nav_menu">
   <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
   <a class="active" id="pricingheader" href="pricing.html"> Pricing</a>
   <a class="active" href="product.html" > Products</a>
   <a class="active" href="about.html"> About Us</a>
   <a class="active" href="community.html"> Community</a>
  </nav>
 </div>
 <button class="gsbutton"></button>
</div>
<div class="main">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="table-row">
    <div class="mycolumn" id="sidebar">
     <h1 class="promo_slogan"> Bring everyone together to build better products.</h1>
     <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="mycolumn" id="content"><img src="">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

[image: button]

Comment: You don't have a button that is type "reset". Add `border: none` to `.gsbutton`

Comment: is this what are you saying and want : https://jsfiddle.net/wdL8qhnc/1/

Comment: @AlwaysHelping This is what is happening and I want to not see that black at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you are not having button type as "reset", so this will not work. add border: none to button class that is .gsbutton
2. After the above change there is one more problem in your code, you are using **"Position" : "absolute"** , that is not needed at all. So you have to remove that. Because of this hover is not getting triggered.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
.gsbutton {
 
 float: left;
 margin: -10px 183px;
 width: 135px;
 height: 50px;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5K46.png);
 z-index: -1; 
}

.gsbutton:hover {
  border : none;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="head_bg">
 <div class="wrap">
  <div class="logo">
   <a href="index.html">
    <img src="file:///C:/Develop/CodeSamples/manage-landing-page-master/images/logo.svg"></img>
   </a>
  </div>
  <nav class="nav_menu">
   <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
   <a class="active" id="pricingheader" href="pricing.html"> Pricing</a>
   <a class="active" href="product.html" > Products</a>
   <a class="active" href="about.html"> About Us</a>
   <a class="active" href="community.html"> Community</a>
  </nav>
 </div>
 <button class="gsbutton"></button>
</div>
<div class="main">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="table-row">
    <div class="mycolumn" id="sidebar">
     <h1 class="promo_slogan"> Bring everyone together to build better products.</h1>
     <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="mycolumn" id="content"><img src="">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you talking about the CSS resets? I will need to add one of them. I didn't think this would cause this issue though.

Comment: This is still an issue and strangely even your code shows the border when I run it though I am using this code in a large part of my code there is still one div that shows the border.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
button[type="reset"]:focus, button[type="reset"]:active, button[type="reset"]:hover {
    outline: none; 
    border: none;   
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.